Extract by location and attribute or two attributes
I have a geopackage with 25 million points and the little laptop that could. The attribute table has a speed and a location identifier for each point. We can call the fields "Speed" and "location_ID". Each "location_ID" has multiple coincident records with different "Speed" Identifiers.
I need to extract the point for each "location_ID" (all points for a single Location_ID are coincident) with the highest value of "Speed"
Virtual layer solutions on other posts have failed me so far, producing empty layers. I am hoping to find the least resource intensive solution as I have a weak computer.

can the geopackage be uploaded to a postgres instance in the cloud? then your reducing the load on the laptop https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/290582/uploading-geopackage-contents-to-postgresql

Unfortunately not in this case.


Order by expression, descending by location and speed fields.
Remove Duplicates By Attribute


Removes duplicate rows by a field value (or multiple field values).
The first matching row will be retained, and duplicates will be
discarded.

The first = highest speed per location will be retained

The only option is to sort by ascending, how would I sort both by descending?

Untick ascending box
